# Having confusion building erofs format system.img for Android

Tags: file-system

I try to edit an Android 11 `system.img` file that was extracted from `super.img`. Now I have an issue that is very confusing to me. First, I extracted `system.img` by this command (The file system is `erofs`, which is used on HUAWEI android devices):

```
sudo fsck.erofs --extract=./extracted --no-preserve --force --overwrite system_a.img
```

And I got a directory tree that contains files like this:

```
.
└── extracted
    ├── 3rdmodem
    ├── 3rdmodemnvm
    ├── 3rdmodemnvmbkp
    ├── acct
    ├── apex
    ├── cache
    ├── config
    ├── cust
    ├── d -> /sys/kernel/debug
    ├── data
    ├── data_mirror
    ├── debug_ramdisk
    ├── dev
    ├── eng
    ├── hw_product
    ├── linkerconfig
    ├── log
    ├── metadata
    ├── mnt
    ├── modem_log
    ├── odm
    ├── oem
    ├── patch_hw
    ├── preas
    ├── preavs
    ├── preload
    ├── prets
    ├── pretvs
    ├── proc
    ├── res
    ├── sec_storage
    ├── splash2
    ├── storage
    ├── sys
    ├── system
    ├── system_ext
    ├── vendor
    └── version
```

Then, I did some modifications and tried to pack it into a `system.img` using this command:

```
sudo mkfs.erofs -zlz4 -Enosbcrc -U00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --ignore-mtime lz4.system.img ./extracted/
```

Everything was perfect, no errors or warnings were shown with this command, and `lz4.system.img` was generated successfully.
I compared two files by using `file` command after finishing the re-packing:

```
@localhost:~/Desktop/extracted_super> file lz4.system.img  system_a.img 
lz4.system.img: EROFS filesystem, blocksize=12, exslots=0, uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, incompat: LZ4_0PADDING
system_a.img:   EROFS filesystem, blocksize=12, exslots=0, uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, incompat: LZ4_0PADDING
```

But I found something different between the one I generated and the original one.

1. File size wasn't the same (later I realized that it is normal because it wasn't signed)
2. There are contents that differ from each other, I am enclosing the screenshot to make it clear to distinguish them:

[image]

As you can see on the right side of the picture, that's the original `system.img`, it contains some of the strings that seem to have something to do with `selinux`, in turn, the new one doesn't have it.

My questions are:

1. What are the strings?
2. What should I do to fix this? Is it because the new one hasn't been signed, so they are not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who don't know the reason for this issue, I have found how to fix it by adding a parameter `--file-contexts=plat_file_contexts`.

Comment: how to add this parameter --file-contexts=plat_file_contexts